# Windows Phone 7.1 (Mango):: Page destructor is not firing

Tags: windows-phone-7

Windows Phone 7.5 (Mango):: While navigating back from a page to previous page using Hardware key, let suppose from Page2 to Page1 the destructor of Page2 is not firing. The destructor of all the traversed pages are firing while exiting application. anybody, please help me with this?

Comment: In C# the destructor overrides the `Object.Finalize` method. You should only override this method if you need to free unmanaged resources. Also, the finalizer is only called when an object is reclaimed during garbage collection. You should not base your application logic on finalizers/destructors.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the OnBackKey Event on you Site to check if its navigated back. Then you should have the same functionality as your desired Destructor

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that the garbage collector doesn't collect that page, that is more likely because you didn't unsubscribe from every event on the on navigated from event.

Answer (score 0):

If the destructopr is really NEVER (*) fired, then it's because something holds a reference to it. Like Igor said, it's probably an event.

Or you override OnBackKeyPress and instead of going back, you navigate forward to Page1. In this case the backstack would keep a reference to the Page2.

(*) Note that the destructor is called not before the GarbageCollector runs. Even if your code is perfect, you might need a couple of Page1->Page2 navigations to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you do not have any class instances with static fields.
Your best friend is the debugger. 
Put this code on top of backKeyPress event

```
if (Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    Debugger.Break();
}
```

and then add watch to any variable that can prevent the call of the destructor.